# node referrer on field collection fields

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a field that was showing node referrer well. I added field collection to the field that is being referenced to by the node referrer. Now I cant be able to see the data that was being referred to.
Has anyone experienced this while using node referrer?

Comment: Are you referring to the node referrer module? If so, please clarify what you mean by "the data that was being referred to"

Comment: i have nodes that represent people. i have other nodes that represent organizations. now the these people work for these organizations. in the peoples node i place a node reference showing which organization they work for. now i have moved this field to a field collection which has other data like what position and when they joined this organization. I was using node referrer to refer back in the organization node to these people, you know like the employees/managers in a given organization. unfortunately i cant be able to see this now after field collection on the peoples node.